# Windows phone 8.1 contacts store issue

Tags: c#, windows-phone, contacts, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on a windows phone 8.1 application and i am currently trying to access the contacts that are a part of different contacts store.

Here in this example,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286416.aspx

it shows how to do this.

My question is, is there a possibility to fetch the contacts based on the contacts store?

Currently i am able to get the contacts from all the contacts store but i just need to get from one of the contact store, is there a way to filter it out. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working,

It was just a Linq query i needed.

```
 ContactResultsData.DataContext =
                    from Contact con in e.Results
                    from Account a in con.Accounts
                    where a.Name.Contains("Sample")
                    select con;
```